# Python Pandas Conditional changes to column filling/filtering correctly

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, conditional-formatting

I am trying to to change the data of a column based on a condition. However, it doesn't seem to pass through the condition correctly and fills every value in the column with the change when it shouldn't. Here is the code:

```
uh['Age']= uh['Age']
uh['AgeStatus'] = uh['Age']
uh['AgeStatus'] = uh.loc[uh['AgeStatus'] > 25.0, 'AgeStatus'] = 'Veteran'
```

and it returns the Type Error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

and the dataframe:

```
   Year   Age   Tm  Lg    G   PA  ...  BB   SO     BA    OBP    SLG  AgeStatus
5  2021  28.0  CHW  AL   88  391  ...  18   87  0.299  0.332  0.437    Veteran
2  2021  23.0  TOR  AL  101  443  ...  29   90  0.296  0.348  0.487    Veteran
8  2021  28.0  BOS  AL   97  409  ...  37   75  0.309  0.374  0.522    Veteran
6  2021  26.0  HOU  AL   96  416  ...  53   80  0.272  0.368  0.476    Veteran
5  2021  27.0  ATL  NL  105  431  ...  30  116  0.249  0.305  0.475    Veteran
2  2021  22.0  SDP  NL   87  362  ...  43  102  0.292  0.373  0.651    Veteran
6  2021  28.0  WSN  NL   96  420  ...  26   77  0.322  0.369  0.521    Veteran
[7 rows x 21 columns]
```

Really confused on what's causing this.

Comment: you should use Age column instead of AgeStatus column for condition  `uh.loc[uh['Age'] > 25.0, 'AgeStatus'] = 'Veteran'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use conditionals like this
`uh.loc[uh['Age'] > 25.0, 'AgeStatus'] = 'Veteran'`